# Tomcat - How to limit the maximum memory Tomcat will use

Tags: memory, configuration, tomcat

I am running Tomcat on a small VPS (256MB/512MB) and I want to explicitly limit the amount of memory Tomcat uses.

I understand that I can configure this somehow by passing in the java maximum heap and initial heap size arguments;

```
-Xmx256m
-Xms128m
```

But I can't find where to put this in the configuration of Tomcat 6 on Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance,

Gav

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Set JAVA_OPTS in your init script,

```
 export JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -server -Xms48m -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

Comment: What does `-Djava.awt.headless=true` do?

Comment: Prevents exceptions is you have some older applications rendering graphics http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/headless/

Comment: And -server optimises for running on a server?

Comment: You can just put `JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -server -Xms48m -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"` in the file `CATALINA_BASE/bin/sentenv.sh` (create it if it doesn't exist). The setenv.sh will be sourced by the catalina.sh if exists.

Comment: zero0's answer is correct.  Putting the values in other places is over-ridden by the defaults in setenv.sh and won't hold.  Just edit setenv.sh  At least for tomcat installed by tarball source, this file is present.

Answer (score 27):

On Ubuntu, the correct way to customize Tomcat variables is by editing the file

```
/etc/default/tomcat5.5
```

(or `/etc/default/tomcat6` if you have a newer version running)

Inside that file, set the JAVA_OPTS variable as described in the other replies here,
for example

`JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx512m"`

to set a maximum memory of 512 MB.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to the `JAVA_OPTS` variable in the `bin/catalina.sh` startup script.

`JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx256m"`

Comment: If you do that, your settings will be lost the next time Tomcat package gets updated.

Comment: @youri is correct. That is the reason you 'd better keep a stand-alone copies of pre-configured vanilla tomcat servers which you just clone for each of your projects

Comment: A comment inside "bin/catalina.sh" recommends to store the environment variable changes in "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh".