# Tomcat - How to limit the maximum memory Tomcat will use In WIndows OS

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-management, tomcat7

I understand that I can configure this somehow by passing in the java maximum heap and initial heap size arguments;

-Xmx256m
-Xms128m
But I can't find where to put this in the configuration of Tomcat on Windows

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tomcat - How to limit the maximum memory Tomcat will use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724820/tomcat-how-to-limit-the-maximum-memory-tomcat-will-use)

Comment: I had a gui application which managed the config changes to bat files had no effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The batch file `catalina.bat` (or catalina.sh for unix) located at `your/tomcat/directory/bin` looks for a batch file (or shell script) named `setenv.bat` or `setenv.sh`. That is where you place your heap size with the JVM -Xms and -Xmx parameters

put this in your setenv.bat (if your `bin` doesnt have one):

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -server"
```

[more info here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40518_01/integrator.311/integrator_install/src/cli_ldi_server_config.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.                                                                                            can you please explain me that what is Xms Xmx and MaxPermSize ?

Comment: You can set the minimum and maximum memory heap size with the JVM -Xms and -Xmx parameters.   MaxPermSize is the maximum limit of the PermGen (Permanent Generation) memory space. check out the link on the answer. HTH

Comment: if you're running Java 8 or higher, the option [`-XX:MaxPermSize`](https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/about-g1-garbage-collector,-permanent-generation-and-metaspace) doesn't apply. The option `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize` needs to be used