# Apache Tomcat Crashes In Google Compute Engine f1-micro

Tags: apache, tomcat, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, centos7

I am running Apache Guacamole on a Google Cloud Compute Engine f1-micro with CentOS 7 because it is free.

Guacamole runs fine for some time (an hour or so) then unexpectantly crashes. I get the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error in Chrome and when running htop I can see that all of the tomcat processes have stopped. To get it running again I just have to restart tomcat.

I have a message saying "Instance "guac" is overutilized. Consider switching to the machine type: g1-small (1 vCPU, 1.7 GB memory)" in the compute engine console.

I have tried limiting the memory allocation to tomcat, but that didn't seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason for the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` is likely due to the VM instance falling short on resources and in order to keep the OS up, process manager shuts down some processes. SSH is one of those processes, and  once you reboot the vm, resource  will resume operation in full.

As per the "over-utilization" notification recommending g1-small (1 vCPU, 1.7 GB memory)", please note that,  [f1-micro](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types) is a shared-core micro machine type with 0.2 vCPU, 0.60 GB of memory, backed by a shared physical core and is only ideal for [running smaller non-resource intensive applications.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#sharedcore).

Depending on your Tomcat configuration, also note that:

> Connecting to a database is an intensive process.

Creating a Tomcat with Google Marketplace, the default VM setting is "VM instance: 1 vCPU + 3.75 GB memory (n1-standard-1) so upgrading to machine type: g1-small (1 vCPU, 1.7 GB memory) so should ideal in your case.

Why was g1 small machine type recommended. Please note that [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/apply-sizing-recommendations-for-instances) uses the same CPU utilization numbers reported on the Compute Engine dashboard to determine what recommendations to make. These numbers are based on the average utilization of your instances over 60-seconds intervals, so they do not capture short CPU usage spikes.

So, applications with short usage spikes might need to run on a larger machine type than the one recommended by Google, to accommodate these spikes"

In summary my suggestion would be to upgrade as recommended. Also note that, the rightsizing gives warnings when VM is underutilized or overutilized and in this case, it is recommending to increase your VM size due to overutilization and keep in mind that this is only a recommendation based on the available data.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I completely understand the need to upgrade, but to keep this free: is there any way to prevent the VM from shutting down processes? I realize this is an intensive process, but it really should not be getting hit hard at all with users.

Comment: Also, it seems to crash not when it is under the most load from a connection, but a couple of minutes afterward.

Comment: The following [community post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724820/tomcat-how-to-limit-the-maximum-memory-tomcat-will-use) has a good suggestion on how you can limit the maximum memory tomcat is allowed. Even if I recommend using Google [Preemptible instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-preemptible-instance), there're still [cost](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#predefined_machine_types) associated to it, but is on the lower end. Nevertheless, there are [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible#limitations)